# Why is SIGTSTP not unblocking in child?

Tags: c, unix, process, signals

A bit lost here. I'm implementing my own shell and one of the features I need to implement is to ignore ctrl+c and ctrl+z when there are no child processes running, but when there are child processes running (like sleep 5 for example), then it needs to kill those processes.

I've managed to successfully block SIGINT and SIGTSTP using a mask in the parent like so:

```
  if ((sigemptyset(&intmask) == -1) || (sigaddset(&intmask, SIGINT) == -1) || (sigaddset(&intmask, SIGTSTP) == -1)) {
    perror("invalid failed to initialize signal mask");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  signal(SIGUSR1, int_handler);

  if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &intmask, NULL) == -1) {
    perror("invalid unable to block SIGINT");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
```

Then in the child I'm sending a `SIGUSR1` signal:

```
 if (fork() == 0) {
    kill(cmd_group->ppid, SIGUSR1);
  }
```

Which is calling the signal handler:

```
void int_handler(int signum) {
  if (signum == SIGUSR1) {
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &intmask, NULL);
  }
}
```

It seems like it's calling the signal handler when I run `sleep 5`, but the process is not terminating with ctrl+c. I should also note that the child processes are in their own process group that is different to the parent.

So why is SIGINT and SIGTSTP not unblocking here?

**EDIT:**

After reading about differences between signal ignoring and signal blocking, I've decided that I'd be better of ignoring SIGINT and SIGTSTP in parent via `SIG_IGN` handler.

And then resetting back to `SIG_DFL` in the child:

**Parent:**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    signal(SIGINT, SIG_IGN);
    signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_IGN);
...
}
```

**Child:**

```
if (fork() == 0) {
  signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
  signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_DFL);

  // execute commands
}
```

For SIGINT it does the desired behaviour: ignores in parent and works in child.

For SIGTSTP however, when I try to kill a child process like `sleep 5`, it causes it to hang forever (doesn't even return from sleep).

What could be causing this?

Comment: The child immediately raises a signal for purpose of testing. Do I correctly understand?

Comment: It might be worth checking whether the child's `intmask` has the value you think. (It probably does have, but when debugging, one can check, if only to eliminate the possibility.)

Comment: How is the value of `cmd_group` set?

Comment: The child throws a signal `SIGUSR1` in order to call the handler which will then unblock SIGTSTP and SIGINT. cmd_group is a custom struct and it's member, `ppid` is simply the PID of the parent, which is assigned at the beginning of my program. How do I print `intmask`? Doesn't seem to work with `%x`...

Comment: I know of no easy way to print `intmask` as such. I am no expert on the topic, but since no expert seems to be present and your question interests me, I am trying to compile it on my machine to see what it does.

Comment: I have tried various things. I do not know, but might the handler be changing the sigprocmask of the wrong process? (But, no, why would it? I believe that mine is the wrong answer.)

Comment: I hope that when you solve the problem you will post the solution and ping me. My curiosity now has half an hour invested. I look forward to the solution! Good luck. But, no, after compiling and running your code, I do not clearly see why Ctrl-C remains blocked. Not knowing what I am doing, I agree with you: it looks to me as though Ctrl-C should unblock, only it doesn't.

Comment: Will do. Appreciate the help !

Comment: We really need a [mcve] to sort this out, but the code you present looks fishy.  It appears that you're delivering a signal to the *parent* process, which ought to then unblock `SIGINT` and `SIGTSTP`, but why?  I would expect it to be *the child* that should be enabled to receive those signals.  It will have inherited its signal mask from its parent, but they don't share -- the child receives a copy, which is unaffected by modifications to the parent's signal mask.

Comment: Thanks that makes sense @JohnBollinger. I've decided to use signal ignoring handler instead and reverting back to default in child. It works for `SIGINT` but still not working for `SIGTSTP`; for some reason when I try to kill a `sleep 5` command with ctrl+z, it chooses to hang forever instead now (doesn't even return from sleep).

Comment: It's not clear to me what you expect in the `sleep` + ctrl-Z case, @doctopus.  Note in particular that the default disposition of `SIGTSTP` is to *stop* the process, not *terminate* it.  I'm uncertain whether the sleep timer should be expected to continue counting, but the process will not terminate before it is resumed or killed by a (different) signal.

Comment: The GLIBC documentation contains a sizable section about [implementing a shell](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Implementing-a-Shell.html).  You might find it useful even if you're not using a GLIBC-based system.